# Pointers in C - finding segmentation fault issues

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around using and setting pointers in linked lists.... I keep getting segmentation faults in my code, anyone see any apparent issues here?

Lately, I'm getting segfaults in every piece of code I write and it's so frustrating because I find them nearly impossible to trace. I'm a physics student trying to teach myself how to code so I am very much a novice programmer and I apologize that I'm asking such a common question, any advice is greatly appreciated!

(To explain the code, we are supposed to create a linked list with nodes that hold three random variables and then sort the list in three different ways, rand_double just generate a random double and runs just fine so I know the issue is not there!!)

```
Node* randomList(int length){

int i;
Node **head, *new;

head = malloc(sizeof(Node**));
*head = NULL;

new = malloc(sizeof(Node*));
new = NULL;


/*create list by adding new node to beginning of list, using 'push' method*/
for(i=0;i<length; i++){

    /*set data in new node*/
    new->value = (int)rand_double(0,10);
    new->key1 = rand_double(10.0, 50.0);
    new->key2 = rand_double(50.0, 90.0);

    new->sort1 = malloc(sizeof(Node*));
    new->sort2 = malloc(sizeof(Node*));
    new->next = malloc(sizeof(Node*));

    new->sort1 = NULL;
    new->sort2 = NULL;

    /*
        set pointers
        new node points to what head points to, head points to new
    */  
    new->next = *head;
    *head = new;
}


return *head;
```

}

Comment: You are assigning new to NULL (which is leaking memory) and then trying to dereference the pointer when you assign new->value.

Comment: Hint : check the sizes -->> `new->sort1 = malloc(sizeof(Node*));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems in your code:

-You are malloc-ing sizeof(Node**) or (Node*)- this is not what you want, you need to allocate space for sizeof(Node).

-You shouldn't have to allocate space to head, it will just point to the first node

-You have several memory leaks where you call malloc and then re-assign the variable

-You only allocate space for new once.  You'll want to move the new=malloc line inside the for loop

-sort1 and sort2 are assigned values but never used

Please address these issues and update the question if you are still stuck.  Good Luck!